# How do I get the textbox to enable after a certain amount of text is inputted?

Tags: vb.net, forms

So my next question(i know i know ive had a lot of questions already but im learning and my teachers suck) 
but I am trying to get the textbox to go to readonly after a certain amount of text has been entered. I know how to make it a read only textbox but only after Ive had one set of data entered. i need it to be readonly after 7 days of data has been entered

I've tried inputtextbox.enabled = false

```
'Validating if user input is a number or not 
Dim output As Integer
If Not Integer.TryParse(InputTextbox.Text, output) Then
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR! Data must be a number")
    InputTextbox.Text = String.Empty
Else
    UnitsTextbox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & InputTextbox.Text)
    InputTextbox.Text = String.Empty
End If

InputTextbox.Enabled = False
```

I'm expecting it to disable after the user has entered 7 days worth of data but it only disables after one day of data is entered

Comment: First things first, do you want the control to be read-only or disabled, because they are two different things?  There is an Enabled property and a ReadOnly property.  Be clear about which one you want.

Comment: As for the issue, you need to determine what condition indicates whether the control state should change or not and when that condition changes.  You then need to put an `If` statement in the appropriate place to test that condition and then set the appropriate property based on that. You haven't actually told us what constitutes 7 days of data, so your question is lacking in that regard. ALWAYS provide a FULL and CLEAR description of the problem. If I recall correctly, each line is one day so you can test the `Lines.Length` property.

Comment: Geez sorry. I need it to be readonly and the enter button disabled

Comment: and i need 7 lines of data with one number on each line and after the 7th number i need the user to not be able to enter any more data

Comment: *"I need it to be readonly and the enter button disabled"*. I meant be clear in your mind. We don't really care as it's setting a `Boolean` property either way, so we don't really need to be involved in that.

Comment: *"i need 7 lines of data"*. Then you need to compare `Lines.Length` to 7, as I said.

Comment: Lines.Length isnt working in visual basic code

Comment: `UnitsTextbox.Lines.Lenght`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the entries to UnitsTextbox are all done in code, this TextBox can be set to read only at design time.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim output As Integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(InputTextbox.Text, output) Then
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR! Data must be a number")
    Else
        UnitsTextbox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & InputTextbox.Text)
    End If
    'Moved this line outside of the If because it happens either way
    InputTextbox.Text = String.Empty
    If UnitsTextbox.Lines.Length >= 7 Then
        Button2.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some simple psuedocode

```
    Private Sub InvalidateTextbox(sender As TextBox, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyUp, TextBox2.KeyUp
    'FOR ANY TEXTBOX YOU WANT TO CONTROL WITH THIS SUB, ADD AN ADDITIONAL HANDLE.
    If Strings.Len(sender.Text) > 7 Then
        '^SIMPLE CONDITIONAL, CHECKING IF THE LENGTH IS MORE THAN SEVEN CHARACTERS, MODIFY THIS TO SUIT YOUR NEEDS.
        sender.Enabled = False
        '^IF THE CONDITIONAL IS TRUE, DEACTIVATE THE CONTROL, IF THAT IS WHAT YOU ARE LOOKING FOR.
        sender.ReadOnly = true
        '^IF YOU WANT READONLY,NOT ENABLED/DISABLED.
    End If
End Sub
```

This code will execute every time a key is pressed while the text boxes are active. What is after "Handles" defines what events will trigger the sub.

sender becomes the textbox object that triggered the sub. e holds all the event arguments for the keyboard, so you can evaluate things like which key was pressed and other neat things.

There was some confusion on if you wanted enabled/disabled or readonly, both options included.